# No parsing from Logstash to remote elasticsearch server

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I've setup two separate servers for logstash and elasticsearch.
Kibana & logstash are on one server, elasticsearch is no different one. Let me call logstash machine as **machineA** and elasticsearch machine as **machineB**.
My elasticsearch.yml file on machineB looks like-

```
path.data: /elastic/elasticDB
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts:
- 1xx.31.3.152
```

Logstash.yml on machineA is-

```
path.data: /var/lib/logstash
path.logs: /var/log/logstash
```

There is a csv file in MachineA's home folder called activity.csv and I want to send it to elasticsearch (machineB).
My logstash config on machineA is-

```
input {
    file { 
        path =>  "/home/cyberuser/activity.csv"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
}   }
filter {
  csv {
  separator => ","
  columns => ["Action Time","Description","Filename","Full Path","More Information","File Extension"]
  } 
  date { match => ["Action Time","dd-MM-YYYY H:mm:ss" ,"MM/dd/YYYY k:mm:ss a"] }  mutate { gsub => ["More Information",",","."] } 
}
output {
    elasticsearch { hosts => ["10.48.xx.xx"] index => "activity" user => "elastic" password => "xxxxxxx" }
    stdout { }
}
```

And all I see on terminal is-

```
Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:200: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings. Continuing using the defaults
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config which logs errors to the console
[INFO ] 2021-09-03 17:02:09.397 [main] runner - Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.14.1", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.19.0 (2.5.8) 2021-06-15 55810c552b OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.11+9 on 11.0.11+9 +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}
[WARN ] 2021-09-03 17:02:09.660 [LogStash::Runner] multilocal - Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[INFO ] 2021-09-03 17:02:10.408 [Api Webserver] agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[INFO ] 2021-09-03 17:02:10.842 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] Reflections - Reflections took 104 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 120 keys and 417 values 
[WARN ] 2021-09-03 17:02:11.607 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] file - Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
[WARN ] 2021-09-03 17:02:11.661 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] csv - Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
[WARN ] 2021-09-03 17:02:11.753 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] elasticsearch - Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
[INFO ] 2021-09-03 17:02:11.916 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//10.48.xx.xx"]}
[INFO ] 2021-09-03 17:02:12.153 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elastic:xxxxxx@10.48.xx.xx:9200/]}}
[WARN ] 2021-09-03 17:02:12.338 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@10.48.xx.xx:9200/"}
[INFO ] 2021-09-03 17:02:12.399 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Elasticsearch version determined (7.14.0) {:es_version=>7}
[WARN ] 2021-09-03 17:02:12.401 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[INFO ] 2021-09-03 17:02:12.551 [Ruby-0-Thread-10: :1] elasticsearch - Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>7, :ecs_compatibility=>:disabled}
[INFO ] 2021-09-03 17:02:12.561 [[main]-pipeline-manager] javapipeline - Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>12, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1500, "pipeline.sources"=>["/etc/logstash/conf.d/activity_view.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x4dd99795 run>"}
[INFO ] 2021-09-03 17:02:13.341 [[main]-pipeline-manager] javapipeline - Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>0.78}
[INFO ] 2021-09-03 17:02:13.378 [[main]-pipeline-manager] javapipeline - Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[INFO ] 2021-09-03 17:02:13.419 [[main]<file] observingtail - START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[INFO ] 2021-09-03 17:02:13.428 [Agent thread] agent - Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
```

Running it from logstash with file parameter doesn't show anything on stdout and no index is created either. There are no logfiles generated in `/var/log/logstash/`.  
However, running logstash and elasticsearch both locally on machineB works fine.
Do I have to make more changes somewhere or something I am doing wrong?
Additionally I wanted to host kibana on port 80, but even after changing kibana port it didn't work. Kibana config is-

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: 0.0.0.0
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://10.48.xx.xx:9200"]
elasticsearch.username: "kibana_system"
elasticsearch.password: "xxxxxx"
```

Comment: Can you check on machineA if elastic is accessible? Try with `curl http://10.48.xx.x:9200/_cat/health`

Comment: 1630675351 13:22:31 elasticsearch yellow 1 1 13 13 0 0 3 0 - 81.3%

Comment: Got the problem now. A stupid mistake. I added `start_position => "beginning"` input and logs started flowing from the file. But the kibana port change issue still remains same.